# How to update from JDK8u20 to JDK8u40?

Tags: java, windows, oracle, updates, auto-update

I currently have jdk1.8.0_20 and would like to upgrade to jdk1.8.0_40. Mistakenly, I updated the java to version 1.8.0_40 thinking it would update the jdk too, but it only updated the jre. Does one need to separately download and install the new jdk version and remove the old one or should it update itself automatically or what?
I've searched and searched but somehow couldn't find any hint. So either I'm missing something and this is really simple or it's not discussed a lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the JDK doesn't auto-update itself. Download the new one and install it.

Comment: When using OSX, it will install all JDK versions in parallel. So you might want to uninstall the old ones.

Comment: So on windows after installing the new one would i have to uninstall the previous version?

Comment: @OmarSharaki-Yes,it's always better to remove older versions after installing a new one,unles the former one is required!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the new jdk deparately but then you have to change your process to use the new one.

As you have not mentioned how you are using the jdk it is a bit hard to know what is needed but in general you should just be able to change your
JAVA_HOME and path variables to point to your newly installed jdk.

Eg If you were using eclipse you would change the jvm entry in eclipse.ini
or change the path in the installed jre configuration in window/preferences.